# app:mergeDebugResources FAILED and The content of elements must consist of well-formed character > data or markup

Tags: android, colors, android-studio, styles, themes

I'm getting 3 errors when I try to run the code. Can anyone help me here with this issue. Please, be elaborative since I'm new to Android App development.

> Error: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character
> data or markup. :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> Error:(9, 9) Error: The content of elements must consist of
> well-formed character data or markup.
>
> Error:(9, 9) Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> res\values\styles.xml:9:9: Error: The content of elements must consist
> of well-formed character data or markup.

The following code is from styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    < item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    < item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    < item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

The following code is from colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="primaryColor">#4CAF50</color>
<color name="primaryColorDark">#388E3C</color>
<color name="accentColor">#9C27B0</color>
</resources>
```

I've tried rebuilding the project numerous times and it's not working. The error seems to be with this 3 lines.

```
< item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    < item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    < item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
```

Can anyone explain what is the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

If you look before the error you will it asks you to add tools:replace="android:theme" since I am assuming you have 2 AndroidManifest files with different themes. So edit main app code accordingly.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        **tools:replace="android:theme"**>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got similar problem in my project. This is due to I write an extra unclosed tag in a layout.

Solution:

1) Just compile your project.

2) Click **Gradle Console**(bottom right corner)

3) Then in gradle console click on "**Run with stack trace**".

4) Now you find the mistake of unclosed tag at that activity.

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

remove the spaces before item, between < and item

I just had a similar problem and figured its the spacing

Update:
Code should be as below,

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
```

Comment: Please, be more specific in your answer, don't hesitate to use the code with your modifcation

Answer (score 0):

This error essentially means that your xml is not correctly formatted. It happened to me while I was merging two branches using the VCS tool. Very important to check all xml files to see if there are no merge conflicts, not just your clases.